# Is there a way to get an easy overview of an NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I'm getting an NSArray filled with something from a helper class. I have a small clue that it might contain NSDictionarys. But i'm not sure. I tried to save the array to a plist but it didn't work because there is probably non plist objects in there.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Does printing the array help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few options.

In the debugger you can put a breakpoint in right after it gets populated and type in `po <variable name>` in the gdb console.  Or you can use the breakpoint and right click it in the variable listing and click "Print Description to Console".

Alternatively, you can use NSLog to display it's contents with a command similar to:

```
NSLog(@"%@", <variable name>);
```

All of these output it's contents in text form to the console, which is accessible via shift-cmd-R.

Answer (score 1):

NSLog([anArray description])

Comment: Should really be `NSLog(@"%@", anArray)`.  It's usually not a good idea to log a string directly.